# JavaScript - Setting property on Object in Image load function, property not set once outside function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Sometimes JavaScript doesn't make sense to me, consider the following code that generates a photo mosaic based on x/y tiles. I'm trying to set a .Done property to true once each Mosaic image has been downloaded, but it's always false for some reason, what am I doing wrong?

```
var tileData = [];

function generate()
{
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function()
    {
        // Build up the 'tileData' array with tile objects from this Image

        for (var i = 0; i < tileData.length; i++)
        {
            var tile = tileData[i];

            var tileImage = new Image();
            tileImage.onload = function()
            {
                // Do something with this tile Image
                tile.Done = true;
            };
            tileImage.src = tile.ImageUrl;
        }
    };
    image.src = 'Penguins.jpg';

    tryDisplayMosaic();
}

function tryDisplayMosaic()
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < tileData.length; i++)
        {
            var tile = tileData[i];

            if (!tile.Done)
            {
                tryDisplayMosaic();
                return;
            }
        }

        // If we get here then all the tiles have been downloaded
        alert('All images downloaded');
    }, 2000);
}
```

Now for some reason the `.Done` property on the `tile` object is always false, even though it is explicitly being set to true inside `tileImage.onload = function()`. And I can ensure you that this function DOES get called because I've placed an `alert()` call inside it. Right now it's just stuck inside an infinite loop calling `tryDisplayMosaic()` constantly.

Also if I place a loop just before `tryDisplayMosaic()` is called, and in that loop I set `.Done = true`, then `.Done` property is true and `alert('All images downloaded');` will get called.

Comment: If `tileData` is empty like in your code, then I'm sure this would work correctly because the for-loops aren't executed. But if it's not empty, then it won't work cause you define functions inside a loop. Could you tell us what `tileData` exactly is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable "tile" in the top loop is shared by every one of the "onload" functions you create; the very same single variable, in other words.  Try this, to give each one its own variable:

```
tileImage.onload = (function(myTile) {
  return function()
        {
            // Do something with this tile Image
            myTile.Done = true;
        };
})(tile);
```

Why is this so?  Because unlike C or Java, declaring "tile" inside the loop like that does *not* make it scoped to the statement block of the loop body.  The only thing that gives you scope in Javascript is a function body.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! Although that syntax is pretty weird to me, I need to learn JavaScript some more.

Answer (score 2):

What I see is that you create closures inside loops, which is [a common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures#section_4). To avoid this, you could create a more general closure, outside the loop, which handles all the load events and executes a function after all images are loaded:

```
// This array must be filled somewhere...
var tileData = [];

var ImageLoader = function(){
    var numOfImages = 0;
    var numLoaded   = 0;
    var callBack    = function(){};

    function imageLoaded(){
        numLoaded++;
        if(numLoaded===numOfImages){
            // All images are loaded, now call the callback function
            callBack.call(this);
        }
    }

    function init(numberOfImages, fn){
        numOfImages = numberOfImages;
        callBack = fn;
    }

    return {
        imageLoaded: imageLoaded,
        init: init
    };
}();

function tryDisplayMosaic(){
    alert('All images downloaded');
}

function generate(){
    // (1) Set the number of images that are to be loaded and (all tiles + penguin)
    // (2) Set the function that must be called after all images are loaded
    ImageLoader.init(tileData.length+1, tryDisplayMosaic);

    // Load this Penguins image
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'Penguins.jpg';
    image.onload = ImageLoader.imageLoaded;

    // Go through each image and load it
    for (var i=0; i<tileData.length; i++) {
        image = new Image();
        image.src = tileData[i].ImageUrl;
        image.onload = ImageLoader.imageLoaded;
    }
}
```

This code is totally different from your code, but it's a lot prettier in my opinion. It requires that you set the number of images that you need to load and a function that must be executed after all images are loaded.

<strike>Note: I haven't tested it, I'm not sure about this `.call(this)` part, maybe the forum could help if it is incorrect.</strike>

I have tested my code and it works fine. Additionally I've improved it, so you save a pointer to the loaded image inside the `tileData` array, see [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/efefo/edit) for a working example.